# Getting empty screen

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am setting the scope with data but all the time getting empty screen.
tried to use some $scope.$apply but it isn't helping.
I can see the scope.items isn't empty...
I can see values only one I click on other tabs.

my code:

```
  .controller('AccountCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
        if (localStorage.getItem("itemHistory") !== null) {
            $scope.items = localStorage["itemHistory"].split(',');
            $scope.$safeApply($scope);
        }
    });
```

tab that navigate to template

```
  <!-- Dashboard Tab -->
    <ion-tab title="History" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="/tab/account">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
```

my temp:

```
    <ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-view view-title="Recent Searches">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                {{ item }}</li>
        </ul>
        </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

thanks for helping!

Comment: does url change correctly? Are you using html5mode in routing? Provide demo that replicates problem

Comment: yes I am getting the correct page but the issue that I cant see my items only when I click on other tabs then it appears. I am using ionic + angular

Comment: need to see demo that replicates this. Can use http://plnkr.co or codepen or similar code share site

Answer (score 0):

I dont see anywhere in your view where the items is being referred. Can you please provide a jsfiddle where I can see the problem? otherwise just looking at this code, I cant make out anything.

And you should not be using explicit apply in this case. apply is a very dangerous call which has to be used with lot of due diligence. It would trigger a digest cycle that trickles up till the rootscope which is what you may NOT want.

Answer (score 0):

I find the issue, it was simple mistake on app.js didnt set the correct view on the app.js